# What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, popular-refrains

What does it mean? Watch her family. If you believe that she is the apple that fell far from the tree, life will teach you to consider.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a source for this or more context? I've answered the idiomatic apple/tree thing below, but 'life will teach you to consider' seems a little odd.

Comment: Please write a title that tells us what the question is about. E.g What does "the apple that fell far from the tree" mean? OR What does "life will teach you to consider" mean?

Comment: Welcome Abeer.  Although this is grammatically acceptable, the meaning is not entirely clear. It doesn't appear to have been written by a native speaker of English.  Please tell us who wrote this and/or where you found it. Thank you.

Comment: The question is doomed to be closed as being "unclear"...

Comment: The way it's phrased, it seems more likely the speaker said, "life will teach you to ***re***-consider."

Comment: This comes from a posting by a Quora user in a thread called "What are some words of wisdom for men?". The posting is titled "MAN RULES", and the actual quote is (#20) "*Watch her family*. If you believe that she is the apple that fell far from the tree, life will teach you to **reconsider**."

Comment: @JEL - Well at least it makes sense now. Do you have a link to the original? Is there any context that tells us who 'her' refers to?

Comment: Abeer - When you give a quote, 1. Please say where it comes from and 2. Please do not change the words.  By changing 'reconsider' to 'consider' you made the sentence meaningless.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, I omitted linking out of sheer disgust (man rules? etc.). [Here you go, though.](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-words-of-wisdom-for-men?share=1#!n=18) It's one of those where you have to scroll to reveal. "Her" is generic, unrevealed, presumably somebody the poster had trouble with, and from whom the poster decided to derive some 'wisdom'.

Comment: Abeer - Others have now provided sufficient context (and a correction) to make the quote understandable.  So that we can answer, please can you say which words and/or phrases you find difficult to understand. Or is Graham Nicol's answer sufficient? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is an idiom “the apple doesn’t fall far from the tree”, which means that children will be quite like their parents.

If “she is the apple that fell far from the tree”, then I assume it means that she is a child who was very different from her parents.

Comment: There is, of course, a variation: "The nut doesn't fall far from the tree."

Comment: @HotLicks, Where the squirrel finds it, then hides it elsewhere.